# How can I parametrize a query with a database name on the SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer

For example, a query fragment what should work:

```
SELECT
  TagName AS Tag,
  Count FROM [##Site1:string?StackExchange.Math##].dbo.Tags
UNION
SELECT TagSynonyms.SourceTagName AS Tag, Tags.Count
FROM [##Site1##].dbo.TagSynonyms
LEFT JOIN [##Site1##].dbo.Tags
  ON TagSynonyms.TargetTagName = Tags.TagName
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I get the error message

> Invalid object name ''StackExchange.Math'.dbo.Tags'.

My naive tries to pass the syntax of both the SEDE and the MS-SQL heuristically weren't successful. How could I make it working?

Comment: Let me check but I'm afraid that will not work as T-SQL doesn't allow the use of an parameter at that place in the syntax.

Comment: @rene No problem - also the negative answer ("it doesn't work") is helpful, because the OP can focus his efforts to alternative solutions (in my case, to solve the same with `INSERT ... EXEC`).

Comment: I  can make it work if you're OK to include the [ and ] in the value you provide: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/683066?table=%5Bstackexchange.math%5D

Comment: @rene Thanks. It is funny, this was also my [first try](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/683068), but it still didn't work.

Comment: But you did enclose the dbname in  [ ] like so `[StackExchange.math]`? Because without those [ and ]  it will blow up.

Comment: @rene Yes. The result is: `Incorrect syntax near '[StackExchange.Math]'.` [Latest try](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/683068/common-tags-on-two-se-sites).

Comment: @rene I specificed also the type (string) and gave a default value. Without them, it works.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was afraid the CTE was causing the trouble. I would have to dig a bit to understand why/how this works.

Comment: @rene Ok, thanks! If you convert it to an answer, it would be ok for an upvote + accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already found out: It Works™.

When you execute an SEDE query with parameters both the SQL statement and parameters are Parsed. Once the parsing is complete it calls a method called `SubstituteParameters` that takes the sqlstatement and all provided values for the parameters. For each parameter that method will, in the end execute:

```
sql.Replace("##" + name + "##", value);
```

Yes, that is correct. A simple string replacement which means you can provide any arbitrary sql statement as a parameter and as long as its result is valid SQL it will execute.

But there is a caveat, which you run exactly into. And that is when you provide a type for the parameter:

```
select count(*) from [##Database:string##].dbo.votes
```

Before the replace is executed, the value is first transformed by this method `EncodeType(parameter.Type, value);`

Based on the type, it takes the value and transforms the value by means of an encoder, which for the string type looks like this:

```
data => string.Format("'{0}'", data.Replace("'", "''"))
```

Basically is takes `Database` and then returns `'Database'` which makes sense if you use a string parameter on an character field of an table. But it screws up the syntax when used to denote a database because this:

```
select count(*) from ['Database'].dbo.votes
```

is not valid T-Sql syntax.

#### Conclusion

Parameters in SEDE are simple name ⇄ value replacements with a few basic checks. If you use a parameter to replace part of your SQL statement, you better not define a type for the parameter so SEDE replaces the value as is:

```
select count(*) from [##Database##].dbo.votes
```

If you do specify a type (string, int, float) validations and/or encodings take place, altering the value of your parameter or rejecting your input.