# How do I search for double quotes in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, search

Long story short, I'd like to search for question containing the text `operator""`.

Comment: Use [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1358307/posts-containing-keyword-in-title?keyword=operator%22%22) that came up [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359600/how-to-escape-single-quotes-in-sede-keyword-search/359601#359601) a few days ago. Searching for symbols is notoriously broken on SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [you can't at the moment.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267937/how-can-i-search-for-special-characters)  You'll have to use an [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1358307/posts-containing-keyword-in-title?keyword=operator%22%22) (credit to @rene and sam.saffron), or the scripts in the linked post.